# Security measures for Thunderbird and Pidgin

Tags: security, thunderbird, pidgin

I want to install Thunderbird and Pidgin. Is it safe to give passwords in these applications. Please tell me what security measures should be taken while using these kinds of applications.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird can encrypt your password if you set a master password. 
Please read for more details: https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/master-password